# R - eliminating duplicate columns in a sparse Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, unique, sparse-matrix

I have an R sparse Matrix (very big. not feasible to convert to a full matrix), I want to identify/eliminate duplicate columns if such exist. similar to unique(x,MARGIN=2), but that operates on sparse matrices.

is there anything like this around?
suggestions about how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a great solution to this either, but this is what I've used.

```
library(data.table)
DFSummary<-summary(DF)
DT<-data.table(DFSummary)
setkey(DT,j)
nDF<-ncol(DF)

dupeList<- list()
dupeList[[nDF]]=NULL
  for(k in 1:nDF){
  dupeList[[k]]<-sort(DT[j==k,i])
  if(k%%1000==0) print (k/nDF)
  }

dupeVec<-duplicated(dupeList)
dupes<-which(dupeVec==TRUE)
```

Keep in mind that this solution would only work for a binary matrix. If you have a numeric matrix, you could do something like paste the i index to the x value. For example
    `DFSummary$ix<-paste(DFSummary$i,DFSummary$x,sep=':')`, and then store the ix values in the dupeList.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use uniquecombs of the transpose in package mgcv and then transpose the matrix. The function works on sparse matrix but returns a dense matrix. This may cause you a memory issue if the matrix you are working with is too big.

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 500
p <- 10/n
pDup <- 1/100
DupRow <- sample(c(1, 0), n, prob = c(p, 1-p), replace = TRUE)
IsDup <- sample(c(1, 0), n, prob = c(pDup, 1-pDup), replace = TRUE)
sum(IsDup)
# 5
myBigMat <- 
     Reduce(cbind2, lapply(IsDup, 
                                function(x) {
                                  if (x) {
                                    toFill <- DupRow
                                  } else {
                                    toFill <- sample(c(1, 0), n, prob = c(p, 1-p), replace = TRUE)
                                  }
                                  Matrix(toFill,nrow = n, ncol = 1, sparse = TRUE) 
                                }
                                ))

NoDuplicateCols <- t(Matrix(mgcv::uniquecombs(t(myBigMat)), sparse = TRUE))
dim(NoDuplicateCols)
# 500 496
```